Huge discrepancy between file size and size on disk. Reduce block size?
If a disk has a large number of very small (1-2kb) files, will reducing the block size save space?
I have a customer with a Windows server. One volume has a huge discrepancy between file size and size on disk. Specifically "Size" is 86.9GB and "Size on Disk" is 2.08TB. The disk has 2.1 million files. The customer confirmed most files are very small, a few kb's.
The drive is formatted with 4096 byte block size. This is the output of "fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo k:"
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo c:
LogicalBytesPerSector :                                 512
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity :                    4096
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance :                  4096
FileSystemEffectivePhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity : 512
Device Alignment :                                      Aligned (0x000)
Partition alignment on device :                         Aligned (0x000)
Performs Normal Seeks
Trim Supported
Not DAX capable
Not Thinly-Provisioned

With a sector size of 4kb, I assume that each of the 2 million tiny files is eating up 4kb a piece. If I reformat with a tiny sector size (like 512 bytes), would the save some space?

Not really because the maximum partition size with 512 byte sectors 2 TB. 16 TB with 4096.

Bummer. I forgot to mention that the drive is 4TB. Would a 1024 byte sector get me to 4TB and save space?

2,100,000 files with a block size of 4096 takes a minimum 8.6GB - this is 2 orders of magnitude less than what you are seeing. The space issue is not block size, there must be some very big files amongst the 2.1 million files

By the way, the output you are looking at for fsutil has nothing to do with the filesystem cluster size. it's showing you the disk "sector size" which has little to do with your question. What you want is fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c: and look for the Bytes Per Cluster

@GregAskew: That limit only applies to MBR partitioned disks. The limit on a GPT disk (regardless of boot mode) is 8 zettabytes with 512b sectors. (Also, OP wasn't asking about disk sectors in the first place, but rather about filesystem clusters.)

I don't think it matters because the cluster size isn't going to be "changed". No one does that instead of getting more storage

It's not the sector size that matters, it's the cluster size - that's the granularity storage blocks get allocated by the file system.
As @JoramandaX commented, use fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo c: to find out the current cluster size. The default is 4K which is good for small files. A volume with significantly larger files should use a larger cluster size though (I tend to use 64K for compatibility).
With a random file length, you lose half a cluster for each file stored. The larger the cluster size, the larger the total loss. However, smaller clusters mean more overhead and more potential fragmentation.
Files with "a few KBs" should be fine with the default 4K clusters. 2.1 million files statistically cause 4 GB to become unusable. At the absolute maximum, you could lose 4095 bytes * 2.1 M = appr. 8 GB.
Since you're reporting a much larger amount, that loss must be due to another reason. Investigate inaccessible (by ACL) or otherwise hidden files, also shadow copies present on the volume.
